# SQL Server data type for money values without rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have numeric values with 6 decimal places after the decimal point which I want to store in MSSQLServer. However, when I use the money type the values get rounded to 2-4 decimal places and I don't want that. What datatype should I use?

Comment: SQL Server docs on [Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187752.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your variable using `NUMERIC(18,6)` data type